# How do I add in app notifications for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to add in-app notifications to my app to alert users about the action they have done. For example, when a user saves something, a small alert on top should come out telling him "hey, I saved this!".

This notification should be like instagram's notifications. You can see how instagram does this by sending a post in direct to someone (something along the lines "post xxx sent to username").

I am not sure how to achieve this, because this is not an actual notification, just something that appears to the user while in-app to tell him they've done something right.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for `UIAlertController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot of third party frameworks that does this. Google for "toast ios", for example. After a quick search I found this library: https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

If you want to do it yourself, you need to create a view with your message, which you can then display.

Comment: Fortunately that library is available in objective-c too! Here it is : https://github.com/scalessec/Toast . This does exactly what I need,  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If they are normal in app notifications (alerts) and not push notifications then the code would be something like this:

```
           let Savealert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Saved!", preferredStyle: .alert)

            Savealert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .dismiss, handler: nil))

            present(Savealert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is an alert that can be used to tell the user they've saved something and then later gets dismissed after the user presses "OK".